# Celery: get all task ids in a graph of tasks

Tags: python, celery, task

I have a graph of celery tasks, and I would like to recover all the tasks id in the graph for other purposes in my app. However, in some setting this does not seem to be possible.

While everything works fine using `as_tuple()` for simple graphs, stuff fails when things are a bit more complicated. For instance let's say I want to run the tasks in `t1` in parallel: wait for them to complete, run `f1`, wait for it to complete, run the tasks in `t2` in parallel, wait for them to complete, run `f2`.

```py
from celery import Celery
from celery import group, chord, states, chain
import tasks
from tasks import add, mul


t1 =[add.s(1,2), add.s(3,4), add.s(5,6)]
f1 = mul.s(2,2)
t2 =[add.s(1,2), add.s(3,4), add.s(5,6)]
f2 = mul.s(3,4)
```

To do so, at first I thought of running a `chain` of `chords`.

```py
chain_task1 = chain(chord(t1, f1), chord(t2, f2))
res1 = chain_task1.apply_async()
```

But after logging `res1.as_tuple()` we can see some ids are missing. In fact I only get 5, whereas our chain of chords consists of at least 8 (i suspect 10).

```py
print(res1.as_tuple())
# Output: (('5ba907d3-6daa-43a6-9c8d-0edaa9b359d4', (('6dcace43-9187-4ae3-8cfb-e5f298e2651a', None), [(('ea493ce4-10ea-43c0-8d1d-7e7d1a6491f2', None), None), (('577f24b7-3bde-47b9-be7a-5db45d07f01d', None), None), (('c29ca951-1a11-489b-83d5-f22bc326c39e', None), None)])), None)
```

After trying out I noticed that when defining our task simply as a `chain` of `groups` and `tasks`, I can get the desired behavior (10 tasks):

```py
chain_task2 = chain(group(t1), f1, group(t2), f2)
res2 = chain_task2.apply_async()
print(res2.as_tuple())
# Output: (('b6125ca6-41f5-4310-8df8-8c632c9ea268', (('8a7bac12-a556-4087-bf20-4de9ccaed22a', (('dd3bd05f-b56c-428a-9ed2-ac09dd2d3960', (('6e5f3fe3-df02-482f-99fc-b9385d74255e', None), [(('e7219ae2-7f53-45ce-b59f-fa168f97b7c4', None), None), (('3804f8ee-ea01-4554-a1c6-66be220ab214', None), None), (('c2a402c0-5401-4931-abf0-4e7275cf198d', None), None)])), None)), [(('1992ef83-836a-457c-8aa4-90875be0ad9a', None), None), (('b9636615-7d24-4af0-9843-9dcfb9163c61', None), None), (('f597050e-e6c4-4c95-9283-681d80ad020d', None), None)])), None)
```

Still I wonder if I am doing anything wrong. I however suspect that there is an issue in celery usage of `parent`. The `chord` `.parent` might override the one of chord, making it possible to build back the full task graph.

Note: the tasks runs properly in both setting, I am just not able to retrieve task ids.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to proactively manage your task set by assigning them ids before `chain()/group()/chord()` freeze them, such as

```py
from celery import group, chord, chain, signature, Task
from celery.canvas import Signature
from celery.result import AsyncResult, GroupResult, ResultSet
import time

t1: Signature = tasks.progress.s(10).set(task_id=str(uuid.uuid4()))
t2: Signature = tasks.progress.s(5).set(task_id=str(uuid.uuid4()))

# t3: Signature = tasks.add.si(4, 4).set(task_id=str(uuid.uuid4()))
# t4: Signature = tasks.add.si(5, 5).set(task_id=str(uuid.uuid4()))
t3: Signature = tasks.log.s().set(task_id=str(uuid.uuid4()))
t4: Signature = tasks.log.s().set(task_id=str(uuid.uuid4()))

task = chord(header=[t1, t2], body=group([t3, t4]))
result: AsyncResult = task.apply_async()

print(f"task: {task}")
print(f"graph: {result.as_tuple()}")
print(f"result: #[{result}]")

res1 = AsyncResult(id=t1.id)
res2 = AsyncResult(id=t2.id)
res3 = AsyncResult(id=t3.id)
res4 = AsyncResult(id=t4.id)

ress = ResultSet(results=[res1, res2, res3, res4])

while not result.ready():
    print(f"result #1, result[{res1.result}] status[{res1.status}]")
    print(f"result #2, result[{res2.result}] status[{res2.status}]")
    print(f"result #3, result[{res3.result}] status[{res3.status}]")
    print(f"result #4, result[{res4.result}] status[{res4.status}]")
    print(f"result set[#1, #2, #3, #4] {ress.completed_count()} {ress.ready()}")
    time.sleep(1)

print(f"result #1, result[{res1.result}] status[{res1.status}]")
print(f"result #2, result[{res2.result}] status[{res2.status}]")
print(f"result #3, result[{res3.result}] status[{res3.status}]")
print(f"result #4, result[{res4.result}] status[{res4.status}]")
print(f"result set[#1, #2, #3, #4] {ress.completed_count()} {ress.ready()}")
print(f"result: {result.get()}")
```